# Javascript API POST from JSON file with fs readFile and map

Tags: json, api, fetch-api

Here with javascript we do an API POST using a external JSON file. Then we have 2 files **order.json** and **app.js**

**my server:**
ubuntu 22.04
node v19.2.0
npm 8.19.3

The script get data from the file order.js using readFile.
**app.js**

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("api-key", "123");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "session_id=123");

// get order.json file
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('order.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err
    let orders = JSON.parse(data)

    let order_line = orders.map(o => ([0, 0, {
        product_id: +o.product_id,
        product_uom_qty: +o.product_uom_qty,
        price_unit: +o.price_unit
    }]));

    let body = {
        partner_id: 150,
        user_id: 6,
        workflow_id: 1,
        order_line
    }

    let raw = JSON.stringify(body);

    console.log(raw);



    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: 'follow'
    }


    fetch("https://mysite/api/sale.order/create?api_key=123", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error))

})
```

the file is located on the path ./ and contain the common order sales from your store.
**order.json**

```
[
    {
        "sku": "123",
        "product_id": "6",
        "price_unit": "9.7",
        "product_uom_qty": "1.0000"
    },
    {
        "sku": "456",
        "product_id": "7",
        "price_unit": "9.8",
        "product_uom_qty": "1.0000"
    }
]
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't create JSON yourself but use something like `JSON.stringify` Second: Why are you sending content-type `text/plain` when you are clearly sending JSON data? Please also post the respecitve headers Postman is sending ... Furthermore have you inspected what your `raw` actually looks like? I assume it contains something like `[object Object]` which results from the implicit `toString()` call that happens when you are building your `raw` string ... This (probably together with a poorly written server) probably leads to an error when parsing your request body ...

Comment: I added my full postman fetch.
I am checking JSON.stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create JSON yourself, but use an existing well working serialization method (like the builtin [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

```js
let orders = [
  {
    sku: 123,
    product_id: 6,
    price_unit: 9.7,
    product_uom_qty: 1.0,
  },
  {
    sku: 456,
    product_id: 7,
    price_unit: 9.8,
    product_uom_qty: 1.0,
  },
];

let order_line = orders.map(o => ([0,0, { 
  product_id: o.product_id,
  product_uom_qty: o.product_uom_qty,
  price_unit: o.price_unit
  }]));

let body = {
  partner_id: 150,
  user_id: 6,
  workflow_id: 1,
  order_line 
}

let raw = JSON.stringify(body);

console.log(raw);
```

Mind that I initialized `orders` from an array instead of reading it from the disk, but that doesn't really matter, assuming that `orders.json` contains valid JSON data. But I noticed, the datatypes in your `orders.json` differs from the datatypes in the data posted through postman. Ie for instance `price_unit` is a string in your JSON, but a number in your posted data. You will need to fix that. I fixed this in the `orders` array in my snippet.

If you can't influence the structure of your json, you can also convert between string and number while creating your object like this (notice the `+` in front of the property access, which converts the string from your order object into a number)

```
let order_line = orders.map(o => ([0,0, { 
  product_id: +o.product_id,
  product_uom_qty: +o.product_uom_qty,
  price_unit: +o.price_unit
}]));
```

I also used [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of the for loop ...

This will create a valid JSON string that can be correctly parsed at the server.

Comment: snippet works so nice, thanks. But notice I need to bring the content of my JSON ìnto the variable let ordres, because is exported from another system. I try to get the content using fs.readFile and parse. But  doesn't work. Whats wrong?

Comment: As I told you, your JSON contains strings for some values (eg `product_uom_qty` notice the quotation marks `'` around the values?) but the API seems to expect numbers ...

Comment: works! you do :) deeply thanks for the explanation.